# ignoring a directory without removing it from the remote

Tags: git

I have a set up where I can push my code to a remote server in order to have it run on production. This have been very helpful an useful, but there is a single directory in my remote that I really do not want to change. The directory is called "images" and it containes images that the users have uploaded, its pretty big and I really dont see any reason to store it on my local muchin.

So I removed the directory with .gitignore, but I noticed some files were still trucked so I perforemed

```
git rm -r images -f
```

and now I am worried pushing to production might remove the directory from my server, which would be catastrophic.

I would very much appreciate any help you can give me.

I am expecting to push to my server without destroying all of my data.

It appears that if I commit now I will lose all of my files, so I tried

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged images
```

expecting it to unmark the content of the directory as deleted, but it changed nothing.

I then attempted to reset to an older commit but the files did not return and are still showing up as deleted for the next commit.

How do I tell git to simply ignore that directory and not update it in the remote?

UPDATE:
I was not able to revert or reset my lost files on my local muchin. So I simply removed the entire directory, cloned the repo again and used
git sparse-checkout
as advised. thank you all.

Comment: "pushing to production might remove the directory from my server, which would be catastrophic" - it would indeed remove the directory from the server, but it would not be catastrophic, because it is still available in earlier commits of the repository.

Comment: "I tried `git update-index --assume-unchanged images` but it changed nothing" - what did you expect it to change?

Comment: Or use `git sparse-checkout` so that you only keep what you want in the working tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Git FAQ is clear that there is no way to ignore tracked files](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files), including using `git update-index`, so that is simply not an option at all.

If you do `git rm -r images` and commit, then when that commit is checked out elsewhere, the `images` directory and its contents will be removed in the working tree.  It sounds like you don't want that, so you probably want to avoid committing and pushing that change.  If you want to restore those files, you can do `git checkout HEAD images`, which should restore those files into the working tree and prevent their deletion from being committed.

If you just don't want it in your working tree, you can use sparse checkout to do so.  You can use it in cone mode, in which case you must specify all the directories you want to include, or you can use it in non-cone mode, which is more flexible, but is slower and has fewer features.  You can see more information with `git sparse-checkout --help`.

Note that unless you're using partial clone (that is, a clone with `--filter`), you'll still have the data in the `.git` directory, but that should hopefully be smaller.  If you do want to use partial clone to avoid downloading unneeded data, you can do a new clone with the `--filter=blob:none` to download only trees, tags, and commits by default, and only download blobs on demand.  This will be faster and use less space, but you must be online to work with the repository.